# TabControl doesn't show the tab collection

Tags: wpf, mvvm, viewmodel, tabcontrol

I'm trying to build a very simple and basic application that adds tab items to tab control using the MVVM pattern.
So i created:
a simple view with one button - "CustomerView.xaml"

an empty ViewModel class - it is empty cause the view doesn't save or extract any information from the Viewmodal (have only one button) - "CustomerViewModel.cs"

The MainWindow class code holds an observable collection of the CustomerViewModel
and have one "Add customer" button - to add a customer tab item to the tabcontrol and the  tabcontrol itself.

i don't use commands cause it is not relevant at this time , i just was the new tabitem to appear when i add a new CustomerViewModel to the collection.

the result is that , although i can see that CustomerViewModels are added to the Observable collection, i still don't see tabitems added to the tabcontrol - The collection is not updating the the tabcontrol.

This is the MainWindow XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="MyViewModalTabControl.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyViewModalTabControl.ViewModal"
    xmlns:vw="clr-namespace:MyViewModalTabControl.Views"

    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:CustomerViewModel}">
        <vw:CustTabView />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="ClosableTabItemTemplate">
        <DockPanel Width="120">
            <Button 
            Content="X"
            Cursor="Hand"
            DockPanel.Dock="Right"
            Focusable="False"
            FontFamily="Courier" 
            FontSize="9"
            FontWeight="Bold"  
            Margin="0,1,0,0"
            Padding="0"
            VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom"
            Width="16" Height="16" 
            />
                    <ContentPresenter 
            Content="Sample" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center" 
            />
        </DockPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>

<Grid Margin="4" ShowGridLines="True">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Button Name="CustTabButton" Content="New Customer" Height="30" Margin="12,136,9,136" Click="CustTabButton_Click"></Button>


    <TabControl Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Background="Red"
                ItemsSource="{Binding CustomerTabs}" 
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ClosableTabItemTemplate}"
                >


    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

This is the code behind of the MainWindow:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ObservableCollection<CustomerViewModel> _customertabs;
    public ObservableCollection<CustomerViewModel> CustomerTabs
    {
        get
        {
            if (_customertabs == null)
            {
                _customertabs = new ObservableCollection<CustomerViewModel>();
               // _workspaces.CollectionChanged += this.OnWorkspacesChanged;
            }
            return _customertabs;
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void CustTabButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        CustomerViewModel CustomerWorkSpace = new CustomerViewModel();
        this.CustomerTabs.Add(CustomerWorkSpace);

    }


}
```

This is the Viewmodel class:

```
 public class CustomerViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

}
```

This is the View :

```
UserControl x:Class="MyViewModalTabControl.Views.CustTabView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <Button Name="CustTabButton" Content="New Customer" Height="30" Margin="12,136,9,136"></Button>
</Grid>
```

What am i missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the fix:

```
public MainWindow()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     this.DataContext=this;   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

where do you set the datacontext for your mainwindow? Your bindings will just work with the right Datacontext.

and wouldn't it be better to create a mainviewmodel too, which handles the stuff you put in the mainwindow.cs at the moment?

EDIT: pls look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) msdn post from josh smith. there you can find a closable tab too.

Comment: I don't set the datacontext at all ,do i need to ? where ? i thought that i need to use datacontext when i have an inheritence of of one control binding to the parent control , or something like that.... here i just have one tabcontrol , thats it.

Comment: if you dont set a datacontext this bindings will never work: <TabControl Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Background="Red"
                ItemsSource="{Binding CustomerTabs}" 
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ClosableTabItemTemplate}"
                >

Comment: This is the josh smith example, only a simple one - only without the MainWindowsViewModel. even the ClosableTabItemTemplate is copy pasted , only without the command. if i don't have MainWindowViewModel (like in the example), where do i set the datacontext? and between which objects?

Comment: look at the post from will to see where you have to set the datacontext. nevertheless you should introduce a mainviewmodel - make things easier :)

Comment: @blindmeis: Thank you, it was the datacontext, i posted the code for the answer and marked my answer as the right answer because i want people to see the code for the answer (it is not entirly clear from your answer). i hope it is ok by you.... thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Try any of the following

- the `ClosableTabItemTemplate` should "return" `TabItem` that will be displayed in the Tab control not the `DockPanel`
- create [template](http://blogs.intuidev.com/post/2010/02/15/WPF-TabControl-series-Part-4-Closeable-TabItems.aspx) for the `TabItem` control
- do it in [code](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WpfTabCloseButton.aspx)